# Calculating Case Due Date excluding weekends and holidays - looking for non coded solution

Tags: case, management

I am searching for a non code way of getting to this;

**Calculating Case Due Date excluding weekends and holiday**

I have a formula which calculates due date excluding weekends, this works great.

I now want to extend this to include (n) number of holidays. I want to store these in either custom setting or custom object then reference from the case. I have tried a number of things using formula fields and workflow rules but hit limitations each time i.e. can't use vlookup or list type custom settings.

Before diving into APEX solution are there any tricks or free apps out there which could help with this?

```
 CASE( MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 0, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c-1)/5)*2, 1, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c)/5)*2, 2, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c+1)/5)*2, 3, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c+2)/5)*2, 4, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c+3)/5)*2, 5, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ CEILING((SLA_Days__c)/5)*2, 6, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) - IF(SLA_Days__c>0,1,0) + SLA_Days__c+ CEILING((SLA_Days__c)/5)*2, null)
```

Comment: CASE( 
MOD(DATEVALUE(CreatedDate) - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 
0, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c-1)/5)*2, 
1, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c)/5)*2, 
2, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c+1)/5)*2, 
3, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c+2)/5)*2, 
4, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ FLOOR((SLA_Days__c+3)/5)*2, 
5, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) + SLA_Days__c+ CEILING((SLA_Days__c)/5)*2, 
6, (DATEVALUE(CreatedDate)) - IF(SLA_Days__c>0,1,0) + SLA_Days__c+ CEILING((SLA_Days__c)/5)*2, 
null)

Comment: Have you looked at Entitlements? It's not exactly a due date, but you can define the window when a case needs to be completed and connect it to business hours which IIRK support holidays as well as weekend exclusions.  That said, the initial setup can be time consuming, but is worth it from what I've seen.

Comment: Yes we took a look at entitlements, but not in detail and like you say the initial overhead of setup put us off. I'm going to revisit this one again on your recommendation. I don't believe our SLA setup is that complex so it may fly.

Answer (score 1):

Entitlements feature fits our need completely. I was please to see it also supports STC like functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this before, and the way around this is a huge pain. You'll need a bunch of helper fields and it's a maintenance nightmare.

I can give you a strategy for a before update/insert trigger in apex. You'll leverage the "Holidays" in SF

Comment: Thanks for your offer. Like you say for something which should be fairly simple; a ton of fields and maintenance becomes a nightmare. Going to revisit entitlements again before moving to code.